# structure in c whose members are also structures

Tags: c, struct, lvalue

I have following `structs`:

```
typedef struct stack {
    void* ss_sp;
    size_t ss_size;
    // ...
} stack_t; 

typedef struct ucontext {
    ucontext_t* uc_link;
    stack_t uc_stack;
    // ...
} ucontext_t;

typedef struct mythread_type {
    ucontext_t context;
    int ID;
    int status;
} mythread_t;
```

Now I have an array as follows:

```
mythread_t mythreads[100];
```

I want to avoid using

```
mythreads[0].context.uc_stack.ss_size
```

for readability reason.

Now I was wondering if the following two blocks of code are equivalent:

- block 1

  ```
  ucontext_t c=mythreads[0].context;
  getcontext(&c);
  c.uc_stack.ss_size=1024;
  c.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(1024);
  ```
- block 2

  ```
  ucontext_t* c=&(mythreads[0].context);
  getcontext(c);
  (c->uc_stack).ss_size=1024;
  (c->uc_stack).ss_sp=malloc(1024);
  ```

What I want is the context of the `mythreads[0]` stack to allocate 1024 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired and answered to quickly. Those are not equivalent.

Comment: i am not understanding why dont you go with  mythreads[0].context.uc_stack.ss_size..... its even better for readability reasons

Comment: @KinjalPatel I just found out for some reason mythreads[0].context.uc_stack.ss_size gives compiler error as well. Is it legal in C99?

Comment: its perfectly valid....whats the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is copy of mythreads[0].context:

```
ucontext_t c = mythreads[0].context;
```

In opposite the following is pointer to mythreads[0] context

```
ucontext_t* c = &(mythreads[0].context);
```

As a result the first peace of code makes modification of the copy (it does not enfluence on the mythreads[0] context), the second one modifies the mythreads[0] context.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equivalent.

The first block operates on a copy of the information in `mythreads[0].context`, the second block operates on the information in `mythreads[0].context`.

You could perhaps achieve overall equivalence if you wrote:

```
ucontext_t c = mythreads[0].context;
getcontext(&c);
c.uc_stack.ss_size = 1024;
c.uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(1024);
mthreads[0].context = c;
```

but there are two extra structure copies in that.